# Removing Multiple Values from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to fix this multi value problem for this XML/ XSLT code but can't seem to figure out whats wrong. For some employees (not all), their record on the output file contains multiple SSN values.  This is causing an issue with the receiving system because it’s only expecting one value. Any Help would be great;y appreciated as I am really stuck with this and need to submit a report in 36 hours. Thank you so much. (Attached are the xml file code and the XSLT code)

***XML:***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
        <pi:PayGroup>
            <pi:Header>
                <pi:Version>18</pi:Version>
                <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>25G</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
                <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Acme.net</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                <pi:Pay_Group_ID>G85D6W87D</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
                <pi:Pay_Group_Name>G85D6W87D Semi-monthly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                <pi:Pay_Period_Start>2013-02-16-08:00</pi:Pay_Period_Start>
                <pi:Pay_Period_End>2013-02-28-08:00</pi:Pay_Period_End>
                <pi:Updated_From>2013-02-28T18:00:15.171-08:00</pi:Updated_From>
                <pi:Updated_To>2013-03-07T12:25:36.860-08:00</pi:Updated_To>
                <pi:All_Effective>false</pi:All_Effective>
            </pi:Header>
            <pi:Employee>
                <pi:Summary>
                    <pi:Employee_ID>1332</pi:Employee_ID>
                    <pi:Name>Robert Paulson</pi:Name>
                    <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>25G</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
                    <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Acme.net</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                    <pi:Pay_Group_ID>G85D6W87D</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
                    <pi:Pay_Group_Name>G85D6W87D Semi-monthly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                </pi:Summary>
                <pi:Personal>
                    <pi:First_Name>Robert</pi:First_Name>
                    <pi:Middle_Name>B</pi:Middle_Name>
                    <pi:Last_Name>Paulson</pi:Last_Name>
                    <pi:Gender>M</pi:Gender>
                    <pi:Birth_Date>1972-07-19</pi:Birth_Date>
                    <pi:Marital_Status>S</pi:Marital_Status>
                    <pi:First_Address_Line_Data pi:Label="Address Line 1" pi:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1">5555
                        Marcos Street</pi:First_Address_Line_Data>
                    <pi:First_Municipality>San Diego</pi:First_Municipality>
                    <pi:First_Region>CA</pi:First_Region>
                    <pi:First_Postal_Code>92109</pi:First_Postal_Code>
                    <pi:Area_Code>619</pi:Area_Code>
                    <pi:Phone_Number>5559999</pi:Phone_Number>
                    <pi:First_Email_Address>bobby@acme.net</pi:First_Email_Address>
                </pi:Personal>
                <pi:Status>
                    <pi:Employee_Status>A</pi:Employee_Status>
                    <pi:Hire_Date>2011-02-28</pi:Hire_Date>
                    <pi:Original_Hire_Date>2011-02-28</pi:Original_Hire_Date>
                    <pi:Continuous_Service_Date>2011-02-28</pi:Continuous_Service_Date>
                    <pi:Seniority_Date>2011-02-28</pi:Seniority_Date>
                </pi:Status>
                <pi:Position>
                    <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Worker_Type>FTR</pi:Worker_Type>
                    <pi:Job_Exempt>1</pi:Job_Exempt>
                    <pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>86.67</pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Rate_Type>H</pi:Pay_Rate_Type>
                    <pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>2013-01-01</pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>
                    <pi:Total_Base_Pay>27.2645</pi:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Currency>USD</pi:Base_Pay_Currency>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>H</pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>
                    <pi:Organization_One>1500</pi:Organization_One>
                    <pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>8810</pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>
                    <pi:Business_Site>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Name>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site_Name>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Region>CA</pi:Business_Site_Region>
                    <pi:Supervisor_Name>Jed Sanders (1402)</pi:Supervisor_Name>
                </pi:Position>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>REMOVE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>SSN</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>123456788</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>SSN</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>111111111</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>ADP_No</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>541</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
                <pi:Additional_Information>
                    <pi:PreferredFirstName>Bobby</pi:PreferredFirstName>
                </pi:Additional_Information>
            </pi:Employee>
            <pi:Employee>
                <pi:Summary>
                    <pi:Employee_ID>1842</pi:Employee_ID>
                    <pi:Name>James Johnson</pi:Name>
                     <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>25G</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
                    <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Acme.net</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                    <pi:Pay_Group_ID>G85D6W87D</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
                    <pi:Pay_Group_Name>G85D6W87D Semi-monthly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                </pi:Summary>
                <pi:Personal>
                    <pi:First_Name>James</pi:First_Name>
                    <pi:Middle_Name>B</pi:Middle_Name>
                    <pi:Last_Name>Johnson</pi:Last_Name>
                    <pi:Gender>M</pi:Gender>
                    <pi:Birth_Date>1982-09-17</pi:Birth_Date>
                    <pi:Marital_Status>S</pi:Marital_Status>
                    <pi:First_Address_Line_Data pi:Label="Address Line 1" pi:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1">1111
                        Hampton Way</pi:First_Address_Line_Data>
                    <pi:First_Municipality>San Diego</pi:First_Municipality>
                    <pi:First_Region>CA</pi:First_Region>
                    <pi:First_Postal_Code>92109</pi:First_Postal_Code>
                    <pi:Area_Code>619</pi:Area_Code>
                    <pi:Phone_Number>5551234</pi:Phone_Number>
                    <pi:First_Email_Address>jjohnson@acme.net</pi:First_Email_Address>
                </pi:Personal>
                <pi:Status>
                    <pi:Employee_Status>A</pi:Employee_Status>
                    <pi:Hire_Date>2010-03-28</pi:Hire_Date>
                    <pi:Original_Hire_Date>2010-03-28</pi:Original_Hire_Date>
                    <pi:Continuous_Service_Date>2010-03-28</pi:Continuous_Service_Date>
                    <pi:Seniority_Date>2010-03-28</pi:Seniority_Date>
                </pi:Status>
                <pi:Position>
                    <pi:Operation>REMOVE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Worker_Type>FTR</pi:Worker_Type>
                    <pi:Job_Exempt>1</pi:Job_Exempt>
                    <pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>86.67</pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Rate_Type>H</pi:Pay_Rate_Type>
                    <pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>2010-03-28</pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>
                    <pi:Total_Base_Pay>27.2645</pi:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Currency>USD</pi:Base_Pay_Currency>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>H</pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>
                    <pi:Organization_One>1500</pi:Organization_One>
                    <pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>8810</pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>
                    <pi:Business_Site>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Name>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site_Name>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Region>CA</pi:Business_Site_Region>
                    <pi:Supervisor_Name>Jed Sanders (1402)</pi:Supervisor_Name>
                </pi:Position>
                <pi:Position>
                    <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Worker_Type>FTR</pi:Worker_Type>
                    <pi:Job_Exempt>1</pi:Job_Exempt>
                    <pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>86.67</pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Rate_Type>S</pi:Pay_Rate_Type>
                    <pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>2013-01-01</pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>
                    <pi:Total_Base_Pay>95123</pi:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Currency>USD</pi:Base_Pay_Currency>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>S</pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>
                    <pi:Organization_One>1500</pi:Organization_One>
                    <pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>8810</pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>
                    <pi:Business_Site>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Name>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site_Name>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Region>CA</pi:Business_Site_Region>
                    <pi:Supervisor_Name>Jed Sanders (1402)</pi:Supervisor_Name>
                </pi:Position>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>SSN</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>222222222</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>ADP_No</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>543</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
                <pi:Additional_Information>
                    <pi:PreferredFirstName>Jimmy</pi:PreferredFirstName>
                </pi:Additional_Information>
            </pi:Employee>
        </pi:PayGroup>
        <pi:PayGroup>
            <pi:Header>
                <pi:Version>18</pi:Version>
                <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>NMA</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
                <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Acme.net</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                <pi:Pay_Group_ID>DS87D7RR9</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
                <pi:Pay_Group_Name>DS87D7RR9 Weekly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                <pi:Pay_Period_Start>2013-02-16-08:00</pi:Pay_Period_Start>
                <pi:Pay_Period_End>2013-02-28-08:00</pi:Pay_Period_End>
                <pi:Updated_From>2013-02-28T18:00:15.171-08:00</pi:Updated_From>
                <pi:Updated_To>2013-03-07T12:25:36.860-08:00</pi:Updated_To>
                <pi:All_Effective>false</pi:All_Effective>
            </pi:Header>
            <pi:Employee>
                <pi:Summary>
                    <pi:Employee_ID>1432</pi:Employee_ID>
                    <pi:Name>Steve Whatever</pi:Name>
                    <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>NMA</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
                    <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Acme.net</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                    <pi:Pay_Group_ID>DS87D7RR9</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
                    <pi:Pay_Group_Name>DS87D7RR9 Weekly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                </pi:Summary>
                <pi:Personal>
                    <pi:First_Name>Steve</pi:First_Name>
                    <pi:Middle_Name>B</pi:Middle_Name>
                    <pi:Last_Name>Whatever</pi:Last_Name>
                    <pi:Gender>M</pi:Gender>
                    <pi:Birth_Date>1985-07-19</pi:Birth_Date>
                    <pi:Marital_Status>S</pi:Marital_Status>
                    <pi:First_Address_Line_Data pi:Label="Address Line 1" pi:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1">1234
                        Dreyfus Lane</pi:First_Address_Line_Data>
                    <pi:First_Municipality>San Diego</pi:First_Municipality>
                    <pi:First_Region>CA</pi:First_Region>
                    <pi:First_Postal_Code>92109</pi:First_Postal_Code>
                    <pi:Area_Code>619</pi:Area_Code>
                    <pi:Phone_Number>5558888</pi:Phone_Number>
                    <pi:First_Email_Address>steve@acme.net</pi:First_Email_Address>
                </pi:Personal>
                <pi:Status>
                    <pi:Employee_Status>A</pi:Employee_Status>
                    <pi:Hire_Date>2009-02-28</pi:Hire_Date>
                    <pi:Original_Hire_Date>2009-02-28</pi:Original_Hire_Date>
                    <pi:Continuous_Service_Date>2009-02-28</pi:Continuous_Service_Date>
                    <pi:Seniority_Date>2009-02-28</pi:Seniority_Date>
                </pi:Status>
                <pi:Position>
                    <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Worker_Type>FTR</pi:Worker_Type>
                    <pi:Job_Exempt>1</pi:Job_Exempt>
                    <pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>86.67</pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Rate_Type>H</pi:Pay_Rate_Type>
                    <pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>2013-01-01</pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>
                    <pi:Total_Base_Pay>27.2645</pi:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Currency>USD</pi:Base_Pay_Currency>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>H</pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>
                    <pi:Organization_One>1500</pi:Organization_One>
                    <pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>8810</pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>
                    <pi:Business_Site>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Name>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site_Name>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Region>CA</pi:Business_Site_Region>
                    <pi:Supervisor_Name>Adam Sandler (5472)</pi:Supervisor_Name>
                </pi:Position>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>SSN</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>333333333</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>ADP_No</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>542</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
            </pi:Employee>
            <pi:Employee>
                <pi:Summary>
                    <pi:Employee_ID>3333</pi:Employee_ID>
                    <pi:Name>James Anything</pi:Name>
                    <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>NMA</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
                    <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Acme.net</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                    <pi:Pay_Group_ID>DS87D7RR9</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
                    <pi:Pay_Group_Name>DS87D7RR9 Weekly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                </pi:Summary>
                <pi:Personal>
                    <pi:First_Name>James</pi:First_Name>
                    <pi:Middle_Name>B</pi:Middle_Name>
                    <pi:Last_Name>Anything</pi:Last_Name>
                    <pi:Gender>M</pi:Gender>
                    <pi:Birth_Date>1975-04-01</pi:Birth_Date>
                    <pi:Marital_Status>S</pi:Marital_Status>
                    <pi:First_Address_Line_Data pi:Label="Address Line 1" pi:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1">9865
                        Wells Lane</pi:First_Address_Line_Data>
                    <pi:First_Municipality>San Diego</pi:First_Municipality>
                    <pi:First_Region>CA</pi:First_Region>
                    <pi:First_Postal_Code>92109</pi:First_Postal_Code>
                    <pi:Area_Code>619</pi:Area_Code>
                    <pi:Phone_Number>5557272</pi:Phone_Number>
                    <pi:First_Email_Address>jany@acme.net</pi:First_Email_Address>
                </pi:Personal>
                <pi:Status>
                    <pi:Employee_Status>A</pi:Employee_Status>
                    <pi:Hire_Date>2012-09-28</pi:Hire_Date>
                    <pi:Original_Hire_Date>2012-09-28</pi:Original_Hire_Date>
                    <pi:Continuous_Service_Date>2012-09-28</pi:Continuous_Service_Date>
                    <pi:Seniority_Date>2012-09-28</pi:Seniority_Date>
                </pi:Status>
                <pi:Position>
                    <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Worker_Type>FTR</pi:Worker_Type>
                    <pi:Job_Exempt>1</pi:Job_Exempt>
                    <pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>40</pi:Default_Weekly_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>86.67</pi:Pay_Cycle_Hours>
                    <pi:Pay_Rate_Type>H</pi:Pay_Rate_Type>
                    <pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>2013-01-01</pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>
                    <pi:Total_Base_Pay>27.2645</pi:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Currency>USD</pi:Base_Pay_Currency>
                    <pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>H</pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>
                    <pi:Organization_One>1500</pi:Organization_One>
                    <pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>8810</pi:Workers_Compensation_Code>
                    <pi:Business_Site>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Name>San Diego Office</pi:Business_Site_Name>
                    <pi:Business_Site_Region>CA</pi:Business_Site_Region>
                    <pi:Supervisor_Name>Adam Sandler (5472)</pi:Supervisor_Name>
                </pi:Position>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>SSN</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>444444444</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>REMOVE</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>ADP_No</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>544</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
                <pi:Identifier>
                    <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                    <pi:Identifier_Type>ADP_No</pi:Identifier_Type>
                    <pi:Identifier_Value>545</pi:Identifier_Value>
                </pi:Identifier>
            </pi:Employee>
        </pi:PayGroup>
    </pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees>
```

***XSLT Code:***

```
<!-- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">

    <xsl:variable name="sep">,</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="pi:PayGroup">
            <xsl:text>Pay Group: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="pi:Header/pi:Pay_Group_Name"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

            <xsl:text>EmployeeID,Last_Name,First_Name,SSN,Hire_Date&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="pi:Employee">

                <xsl:value-of select="pi:Summary/pi:Employee_ID"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="pi:Personal/pi:Last_Name"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="pi:Personal/pi:First_Name"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="pi:Identifier[pi:Identifier_Type = 'SSN']/pi:Identifier_Value"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="pi:Status/pi:Hire_Date"/>

                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>  <!-- end employee loop -->

            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        </xsl:for-each>  <!-- end paygroup loop -->

    </xsl:template> <!-- end of main template -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It looks like you are receiving a sequence of updates and must decide based on the operations whether or not an SSN is present and which one to keep.  What does the specification say about operation order?  For a given `Identifier_Type`, are the operations ordered with the most recent one first or last?  Note that if the "most recent" (whichever one it is) is `REMOVE` then that record does not have an SSN.  The problem is under-specified and the question cannot be answered in its present form.

Comment: @JimGarrison...It has to be the most recent SSN if there are multiple values. I'm a newbie to XSLT so I apologize for the vague explanation. Thank you so much for your immediate response, appreciate it :)

Comment: The issue is there's not enough information to determine the order of updates, which makes a big difference. You need to ask the supplier of the XML which one it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It has to be the most recent SSN if there are multiple values

I agree with previous comments and answers that this is a little sketchy requirement. In the source there is nothing that suggests "most recent". There are several possible conclusions, that you will have to check with whoever has the specification of your input XML:

- the most recent is also the last, use:

  ```
  <xsl:value-of select="pi:Identifier[pi:Identifier_Type = 'SSN']
      [last()]/pi:Identifier_Value"/>
  ```
- the most recent is always the first, use:

  ```
  <xsl:value-of select="pi:Identifier[pi:Identifier_Type = 'SSN']
      [1]/pi:Identifier_Value"/>
  ```
- the most recent is the last, but may *not* have a certain "operation" (as suggested by Michael):

  ```
  <xsl:value-of select="pi:Identifier[pi:Identifier_Type = 'SSN' 
      and not(pi:Operation='REMOVE')][last()]/pi:Identifier_Value"/>
  ```
- anything else (fill in the blanks)

Comment: Abel and Michael...Thank you so very much for all the help. I really appreciate your prompt responses . Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any guidance regarding which of the SSN numbers to pick, and with only a single example to go by I am largely guessing here. Try replacing:

```
<xsl:value-of select="pi:Identifier[pi:Identifier_Type = 'SSN']/pi:Identifier_Value"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="pi:Identifier[pi:Identifier_Type = 'SSN' and not(pi:Operation='REMOVE')]/pi:Identifier_Value"/>
```

This is based on the assumption that whenever an SSN is being REMOVEd, there will be another one (and only one) ADDed - and that's the one you want to have in your output. Of course you'll have to consult your source XML's schema in order to verify such assumption.